# How to build a React app (containing SVG files) inside a SilverStripe project so SS4 folder conventions are maintained?

Tags: reactjs, silverstripe-4

I have been using `npm run build`to create build files for my React project which automatically produces three folders in the build directory inside the React project `static/js`, `static/css` and `static/media` (containing the SVG files). The first two folders `static/js` and `static/css` can be dealt with by using the SilverStripe `Requirements` class on the `init` method of the ReactPageController (the PageController for the SilverStripe layout with the nested React app), adding the paths to the composer.json file

```
"extra": {
        "expose": [
            "app/react-complete-guide-app/build/static/js",
            "app/react-complete-guide-app/build/static/css",

        ],
```

and running `composer vendor-expose` to create SymLinking in the `SilverStripeProject/public/app/react-app` directory.

The media file is not so easy beacause the `Requirements` class of SilverStripe only deals with JavaScript or CSS files. ALso the script `npm run build` automatically configures the relative path of the `react-app` build files without considering the SilverStripe project structure that it will be nested within e.g. the relative path after `npm run build` is `/static/media/icon.svg`.

To get the `static/media/icon.svg` files to be picked up by the virtual host means I have to manually place a copy of the `static/media` folder (containing the icons for the site as svg files) in the `my-SS4-project/public` directory. I want to place the svg files in the `my-SS4-project/public/resources` folder where they should be located. But then I can't point the virtual host at that folder without the virtual host losing access to the SymLinks for the static/js and static/css build folders.

The generated build folder paths and files are:

```
build/static/js:

- main.f8fcfe77.js
- main.f8fcfe77.js.map

build/static/css:

- main.417390ae.css
- main.417390ae.css.map

build/static/media:

- bottom_image_height_improved_enlarged.0242eccb.svg
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a5.woff2
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.89889688.svg
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.e18bbf61.ttf
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.f4769f9b.eot
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.fa277232.woff
- ic_cloud_download.0258cc94.svg
- ic_cloud_upload.6bf269d8.svg
- ic_help.bb8f97ab.svg
- ic_local_download.ddb824a7.svg
- ic_menu.7f39fb5c.svg
- ic_new.57667fef.svg
- ic_open.ddb824a7.svg
- ic_print.420fc2c5.svg
- ic_save.3fee4fd0.svg
- logo.d6c538c9.svg
- master_menu_cancel_btn.53591bb8.svg
```

Below shows the CircleAppPageController.php file using the init function and Requirements class to bring in the JavaScript and CSS files from the react-app build files. Note: react-app is nested inside the SilverStripe project app folder.

```
<?php
namespace SilverStripe\Lessons;

use SilverStripe\View\Requirements;

use PageController;    

class ReactAppPageController extends PageController 
{
    protected function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        // Requiring build files for react-app - Doesn't include media folder files!
        Requirements::javascript('app/react-app/build/static/js/main.f8fcfe77.js');
        Requirements::css('app/react-app/build/static/css/main.417390ae.css');

    }
}
?>
```

Here is where the react-app to appears in the layout of the ReactAppPage.ss (Note: ReactAppPage.php class extends Page.php class. The layout for Page.ss includes a simple navbar, header and footer which ReactAppPage.ss will inherit).

```
<% include Banner %>
<!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="main col-sm-8"> 
                        <div>

                            <div id="root">
                                I want the react-app with it's independent CSS stylings to appear here.
                            </div>

                        </div>                  

                    </div>

                    <div class="sidebar gray col-sm-4">
                        <% if $Menu(2) %>
                        <h3>In this section</h3>
                            <ul class="subnav">  
                                <% loop $Menu(2) %>
                                    <li><a class="$LinkingMode" href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></li>
                                <% end_loop %>
                            </ul>
                        <% end_if %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->
```

I am new to all this and have been advised to try writing a DOS batch script to automatically do all the manual hack I am doing to get the icons to work every time something changes in my `react-app` requiring a new build.

I have researched a lot and read that SS4 decided to not let the public folder be configurable. Also SS4 dropped support for SVG files in December 2018 fro security reasons. I have also heard that changing the build paths of the SVG files post build is possible with the SilverStripe 4 back end. Any thoughts about this would be great.

The expected results would be that I can automate the build process as much as possible and have the files in the correct place in the SilverStripe project. Maybe I am trying to do something more complicated than needed?