# 1st Batch File attempt - trouble with asynchronous commands

Tags: reactjs, batch-file, silverstripe-4

I am trying to write my first ever batch file that builds a React application (using node package manager) nested inside a SilverStripe project, and renames the js and css build files, and moves the media build files to a new directory within the SilverStripe project (so they can be picked up by a virtual host configured to point at the SilverStripe project).

To start the script in cmd I use the following script name with two arguments:

```
updateReactInSS "C:\wamp64\www\example5" "C:\wamp64\www\example5\app\moe-card-app"
```

The script does successfully executes npm run build but doesn't continue after that. My hunches are:

- Something asynchronous could be going on? I added a timeout for this but might have syntax wrong. The following line never runs:
  echo "TIMEOUT finished. Script continuing..."
- I might have my syntax wrong to get to the right directories?

Below is the full script:

```
Rem ============================================================================================
Rem This batch script builds a React Application inside SilverStripe and
Rem moves media files if they exist to the public directory of the SilverStripe project.
Rem command line argument 1 = full path to the nested SilverStripe project folder
Rem command line argument 2 = full path to the nested React application
Rem It relies on node package manager and composer being installed.
Rem The result works with a virtual host configured to point at the SilverStripe project folder.
Rem =============================================================================================
@echo off
Rem Checking argument 1 entered correctly.
if "%~1"=="" (
echo You forgot to specify the full path to the SilverStripe project folder:
echo argument 1 = ?
goto finished
) else (
echo argument 1 = The path to the SilverStripe project folder is:
echo %1
)
Rem Checking argument 2 entered correctly.
if "%~2"=="" (
echo You forgot to specify the full path to the nested React application:
echo argument 2 = ?
goto finished
) else (
echo argument 2 = The path to the nested React application is:
echo %2
)
Rem Going to React application path. NOTE: could also add condition to check npm install if 1st time run
cd %2
cd
Rem Delete build directory if it exists. Using node package manager to build the React application.
if exist build\ del build /s /e
npm run build
Rem Adding time for npm run build to finish before continuing
TIMEOUT /T 20
echo TIMEOUT finished. Script continuing...
Rem Rename main.hashcode.js to main.bundle.js so consistent with requirements in related SS page controller.
cd %2\build\static\js
cd
rename main.*.js "main.bundle.js"
Rem Rename main.hashcode.css to main.bundle.css so consistent with requirements in related SS page controller.
cd %2\build\static\css
cd
rename main.*.css "main.bundle.css"
Rem Going to to SilverStripe project root to run composer vendor-expose command creating sym-links if not there.
cd %1
composer vendor-expose
Rem Copying media build files if media directory exists in React build files to the public folder in SilverStripe. project.
if exist %2\build\static\media (
MD \public\static\media
xcopy %2\build\static\media %1\public\static\media /s /e
) else (
goto finished
)
if errorlevel 4 goto lowmemory
if errorlevel 2 goto abort
if errorlevel 0 goto exit
:lowmemory
echo Insufficient memory to copy files or
echo invalid drive or command-line syntax.
goto exit
:abort
echo You pressed CTRL+C to end the copy operation.
goto exit
:finished
echo The programme updateReactInSS has completed.
:exit
```

Here is a related question I asked on this on StackOverFlow with more detail about what I am trying to achieve. If you answer this question you also answer that one = 2 birds with one stone!!!

- [How to build a React app (containing SVG files) inside a SilverStripe project so SS4 folder conventions are maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052324/how-to-build-a-react-app-containing-svg-files-inside-a-silverstripe-project-so)

Comment: The best I can offer at this time is that you learn how each command works. To do that you can access the help information for each one by entering the command name, followed by its help option, `/?` at the Command Prompt. Additionally, you should use `Rem` for remarks, not malformed labels, `::`. To check for empty arguments, you should use, `If "%~1" == ""`, and to check the existence of a directory as opposed to a file, you should use a trailing backslash, `if exist build\ `. I'd also suggest that you surround none `echo` strings with doublequotes, e.g. `If Exist "build\"` and `CD "%~1"`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will make those changes to the script and edit this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround to this problem was to break the original single script into 2 scripts that can be run in the command line. This split was necessary to continue after `npm run build` finishes and if `composer vendor-expose` needs to be run and finishes. This is because my script is automatically exited when they finish. Below are the two scripts with arguments:

updateReactInSS_1 "C:\wamp64\www\silverstripeProject" "C:\wamp64\www\silverstripeProject\app\ReactApp"

```
Rem =======updateReactInSS_1=============
Rem updateReactInSS_1 is part 1 of 2 that updates a React Application nested inside a SilverStripe project.
Rem It deletes an existing React application build directory and rebuilds it with npm.
Rem Dependencies are node package manager (npm) and Composer installed globally by editing the
Rem environment variable path on your machine so they can be run from the command line (cmd).
Rem You also need a virtual host configured to point at your-SilverStripe-project folder.
Rem Argument 1 = full path to the nested SilverStripe project folder
Rem Argument 2 = full path to the nested React application
Rem updateReactInSS_1 file is located at Argument 2.
Rem updateReactInSS_2 file is located at Argument 2. It renames the "hash" js and css build files to "bundle"
Rem then copies and moves existing media build media files to the public directory of the SilverStripe project.
Rem Note: If "composer vendor-expose" runs then updateReactInSS_2 needs to be run again to complete the script.
Rem =======START===========
@echo off
Rem Checking argument 1 entered correctly.
if "%~1"=="" (
echo You forgot to specify the full path to the SilverStripe project folder:
echo argument 1 = ?
goto exit
) else (
echo argument 1 = %1 (path to the SilverStripe project folder)
)
Rem Checking argument 2 entered correctly.
if "%~2"=="" (
echo You forgot to specify the full path to the nested React application:
echo argument 2 = ?
goto exit
) else (
echo argument 2 = %2 (path to the nested React application)
)
Rem Going to React application path (NOTE could also add condition to check npm install if 1st time run)
cd %2
Rem Deletes the React application build directory if it exists and then use node package manager to build the React application.
if exist build\ del build /s /e
npm run build
:exit
```

updateReactInSS_2 "C:\wamp64\www\silverstripeProject" "C:\wamp64\www\silverstripeProject\app\ReactApp"

```
Rem updateReactInSS_2 is part 2 of 2.
Rem Argument 1 = full path to the nested SilverStripe project folder
Rem Argument 2 = full path to the nested React application
Rem updateReactInSS_2 file is located at Argument 2 (where updateReactInSS_1 is forced to end by npm run build).
Rem It renames the "hash" js and css build files to "bundle" and copies and moves
Rem existing build media files to the public directory of the SilverStripe project.
Rem Note: If updateReactInSS_2 is forced to end by composer vendor-expose command at Argument 1,
Rem you need to cd to Argument 2 to run updateReactInSS_2 again to complete the script. 
Rem If symlinks have already been created by Composer, the command composer vendor-expose is
Rem skipped so updateReactInSS_2 only needs to be run once from the command line. 
Rem =======START=======
@echo off
Rem Checking argument 1 entered correctly.
if "%~1"=="" (
echo You forgot to specify the full path to the SilverStripe project folder:
echo argument 1 = ?
goto finished
) else (
echo argument 1 = %1 (path to the SilverStripe project folder)
)
Rem Checking argument 2 entered correctly.
if "%~2"=="" (
echo You forgot to specify the full path to the nested React application:
echo argument 2 = ?
goto finished
) else (
echo argument 2 = %2 (path to the nested React application)
)
Rem Rename main.hashcode.js to main.bundle.js so consistent with requirements in related SS page controller.
cd %2\build\static\js
rename main.*.js "main.bundle.js"
Rem Rename main.hashcode.css to main.bundle.css so consistent with requirements in related SS page controller.
cd %2\build\static\css
rename main.*.css "main.bundle.css"
Rem checking if composer vendor-expose needs to run to create symlinking.
cd %1\public\resources
if not exist app\moe-card-app\build\ (
echo Please cd to %2 and run updateReactInSS_2 again to complete script commands.
cd %1
composer vendor-expose
)
Rem Go to public folder of SilverStripe project if no static\media directory exists, make it.
cd %1\public
if not exist static\media\ (
MD 1%\public\static\media
)
Rem Copying media build files if media directory exists in React build files to the public folder in SilverStripe. project.
if exist %2\build\static\media\ (
xcopy %2\build\static\media %1\public\static\media /s /e
) else (
echo No media directory to copy in react build\static\
goto exit
)
if errorlevel 4 goto lowmemory
if errorlevel 2 goto abort
if errorlevel 0 (
cd %2
goto finished
)
:lowmemory
echo Insufficient memory to copy files or
echo invalid drive or command-line syntax.
goto exit
:abort
echo You pressed CTRL+C to end the copy operation.
goto exit
:finished
echo updateReactInSS_2 COMPLETED
:exit
```

Please comment with better design solutions. Can they be made into one script or controlled by a third script so only one command needs to be entered into the command line? I am learning and am bound to have done things contrary to best practice and conventions here!!!!! Thank you so much for your time and sharing your knowledge on StackOverflow :-).